# Prevent scrolling below a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is my div structure.

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
   <div id="inner1"></div>
   <div id="inner2"></div>
   <div id="inner3"></div>
   <div id="inner4"></div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent scrolling below `$('#inner3')` when a button is clicked?

I tried several things. 
I used `style="display:none;`. That prevents from scrolling but I need it visible at all times. I just want to prevent the user seen it.

I used `style="visiblility:hidden;`. WHen I did this the bottom area of the page is blank. It looks odd.

So is there any way that I can hide `$('#inner4')`?

Comment: any jsfiddle or demo?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: So if you don't want people to scroll passed `#inner3` why does it matter that `#inner4` is not visible using `display: none`, it would never be seen anyway? Your question is confusing. You state that the div should be visible, not hidden, but people shouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: @BenM: I've tried to do this using css (as mentioned in my post).

Comment: @Becky Yes, I mean that you should share your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: thanks. `$('#inner4')` contains some canvas + png which I need to use with html2canvas. So having `display:none` prevents html2canvas from drawing canvas/png.

Answer (score 0):

You can do absolute position on inner4 then it won't be there, but still in dom.

```
#inner4 {
   position: absolute;
   left: -9999999px;
}
```

Comment: how is it different from display: none?

Comment: with display:none sometimes somethings become inactive. So my guess is that's what OP is running into therefore doesn't want display:none

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: you're correct. That wan't a good solution though I thought that is... apologies.

Comment: what wasn't good about it, explain so we can see why you don't want display none

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there should be a better alternative. But this jQuery function does exactly what you want:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        var elem = $('#inner3');
        var breakPoint = elem.offset().top - ( $(window).height() - elem.height() );
        if( winTop>breakPoint ) {
            $(window).scrollTop( breakPoint );
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zfph6w1/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
#inner4 {
overflow: hidden;
height: 0px;
padding: 0px;
min-height: 0px;
max-height: 0px;
}
```